# Short sci fi story where a space craft is made of various creatures from all over universe

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for the title of a short story where a space craft is made up of various creatures from around the universe.

If I remember correctly the skin of the craft is made of creatures. the computer is just a giant brain. The engine creature suffers some form of malfunction and a nearby suitable replacement is located which happens to be a human. Although not as good as the original the human will suffice. At first he is reluctant but then discovers he loves it. I think they call propelling the craft as "pushing".

I hope somebody can help. I had this book many years ago and I don't know what I have done with it.

Answer (score 20):

*Specialist* by Robert Sheckley.

Plot description from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialist_%28short_story%29) (which agrees with what I remember of this story)

> A galactic deep-space cargo ship is blown off course by a photon
>  storm. When the crew recover, they don't know their location in space
>  and one of their members, known as Pusher, is dead.
>
>  The Crew comprises varied members of vastly different intelligent
>  races, all in close mental rapport known as the Cooperation, and
>  serving specialized functions; they are known as Engine, Thinker, Eye
>  etc. But without a Pusher, they cannot accelerate to ftl speeds. They
>  manage to locate a planet known to be rich in primitive Pushers,
>  Earth. They try to communicate with a man they find, but he is so
>  violent and resistant that they are forced to bring him on board the
>  ship to try to reason with him.
>
>  Gradually, the man begins to realize the nature of the Crew and the
>  pleasure to be found as a part of the mental Cooperation. He agrees to
>  join the crew. Hesitantly at first, he tries to Push and finally
>  learns how it is done. The ship speeds away at eight times the speed
>  of light and accelerating.

It appears in quite a lot of anthologies (see [isfdb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45711))